# How to close existing open tab in browser if we click a link in the current tab using angular 7?

Tags: angular

I need to close an existing open tab from the current tab if i click the link in chrome using angular 7.

My current scenario is if i am clicking a link in the current tab using

```
window.open('http://somedomain.com');
```

it will open a new tab, but my new scenario is i need to ensure that if same url is existing in another tab to be closed dynamically using angular and open the tab for which the link is clicked.

To clearly say If SomeDomain tab is already opened, system should close the existing tab and open new tab.

Can someone help me out for this, you can share me any reference which will be helpful for me. Since i don't know how to control of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, this seems possible. Due to the security reason chrome or most of browser doesn't allow to do this, like closing a tab from another tab(if its allowed you can close any other tabs of the user and that's a very major issue of accessibility and user consent).

You can only close a tab or window, if that has been opened programmatically from JavaScript(not by a user click).

Your scenario is very common, most of the bank and financial web app implemented this. Doesn't allow two tab for the same domain or app.

This can be achieved by session tracking or any session data that you store in browser.

Eg. I open a tab, login to URL and have session data in localStorage. Now whenever user open that link again in another tab, check the localStorage and if you have session available, don't render the page. Render some message and a close button to close the tab(when user click).

How we can achieve this functionality is differ based on the nature and security of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Completely Agree with what @AbhinavKumar said, it is not possible to close other `tabs` due to security and accessibility.

But there is a way to close other tabs, **if it is only opened by your application** using angular.

For closing other tabs, you must have `handler` of it, which you can get while opening the `tab`.

I have implemented sample code in `component` of angular. you can use it in `component` only if that is the single `source` of opening new `tab`. However, I recommend you to generate separate `shared service` for it, generate `singleton` instance of it in `AppModule` using `forRoot()` metho and store your `handlers` in `service`.

Below the code for your problem.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TestStack';
  windows = [];

  openNew(){    
     this.resetWindowsAndCloseTabs();
     this.windows.push(window.open('https://somedomain.com'));
  }

  resetWindowsAndCloseTabs(){
     this.windows.forEach(element => {
       element.close();
     });
     this.windows = [];
  }
}
```